# Meu aplicativo é feito em webview e ao clicar em voltar com o botão do celular android ele mostra a msg launcher parou

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-webview

1. Este é o meu código MainActivity.java quando executado em um dispositivo eu clico no botão voltar simplesmente aparece a mensagem Launcher parou

Preciso muito entender o que está faltando no código o meu principal conceito de erro está em toda a parte do (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack())

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Object WebResourceRequest;
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("https://oolze.com.br/");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // mostra a progress
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // esconde a progress
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
 }
```

**Meu activity_main.xml**
*Aqui ficam o xml da activity onde fica a webview e a barra de progresso*

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está criando e inicializando uma variável local chamada `webView` e não a variável de instância de mesmo nome. Deveria inicializar a variável de instância.

Em outras palavras, troque essa linha:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

por essa:

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Outra coisa, não sei se o efeito é o mesmo, mas em vez de sobrescrever `onKeyDown()` sugiro sobrescrever `onBackPressed()`, ele foi feito para ser sobrescrito em casos como esse.

Comment: Muito obg, deu certoooooo !!!! estava quebrando a cabeça por causa de uma linha de código kkkk

Comment: Se a resposta serviu, marque ela como aceita. Veja no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) como fazer.